# Copy div And his style to new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to copy a div to a new window for printing, That's working fine
but the div his copied without any style attached to it.

```
  $('#PrintNews').bind('click', function () {
        var printContents = new $("#divToPrint").clone();           
        var myWindow = window.open("", "popup", "width=1000,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes," +
            "toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=0,top=0");
        var doc = myWindow.document;
        doc.open();
        $(printContents).find("#PrintNews").remove();
        doc.write($(printContents).html());
        doc.document.close();
        doc.focus();
        doc.print();
        doc.close();
  });
 });
```

How can i open that div in a new window for printing, but with all of his styles like in the original div?

Comment: Is your original div you copy over styled with inline styles, or from an external ccs file?

Comment: It will only copy inline styles when you do that.  Any styles coming from stylesheets or (ugh) a `<style>` tag will not be copied.

Comment: Its coming from external css. So what is my options?

Comment: `doc.write('<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />')` before the other `doc.write()` would be an option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should build the html of new window something like this, to link extarnal css files.

```
    doc.write("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">");
    doc.write("<html>");
    doc.write("<head>");
    doc.write("<link href='/css/print.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />"); // your css file comes here.
    doc.write("</head>");
    doc.write("<body>");
    doc.write($(printContents).html());
    doc.write("</body>");
    doc.write("</html>");
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because styles had not been loaded before printing.

```
var showPrintWindow = function (context) {
        var printWindow = window.open('', '');
        var doc = printWindow.document;
        doc.write("<html><head>");
        doc.write("<link href='/css/printReport.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='print' />");
        doc.write("</head><body>");
        doc.write(context);
        doc.write("</body></html>");
        doc.close();

        function show() {
          if (doc.readyState === "complete") {
              printWindow.focus();
              printWindow.print();
              printWindow.close();
          } else {
              setTimeout(show, 100);
          }
        };
        show();
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the way the div is styled.  If the styles are applied based on the ID or class then you should be fine to just include the same stylesheet in the new window.  However if any of the styles are based on the element's ancestors then it becomes tricky as you would have to copy the ancestral elements in order for the exact styles to be applied.

It sounds like you ought to be using print-specific styles.  You can apply a stylesheet to print only by including the `media="print"` attribute on the stylesheet link.  This stylesheet is then responsible for hiding any elements in the page that you don't want to print and positioning the ones that you do.  This way you are not subject to popup blockers and give the user one less step to print the document.

You can achieve the same by using media queries in your original stylesheet.  Here is a very simple example:

```
@media print {
    .print {width:100%;}
    .noPrint {display:none;}
}
```

To test this just remove the @media wrapper and see how it looks in your browser.  It should give you a pretty good idea of how the page will look on paper.

Comment: Yes i know what it is. My only problem is that it open a big window for printing option - i want to re size it.. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't believe so - the print window is dependent on the browser - for instance Chrome's print window is very different from the one used by most other browsers.  Even so, you would surely have the same problem when the user tries to print whatever appears in the popup?

Comment: I don't care for the look of the printing page - only the size, if i re-size the window then its automatically re-size the printing window

Comment: `window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');`
May be this would help @EranMeir

Answer (score 0):

Include external css into the window to which you are copying your DIV. otherwise only the inline styles will be copied.