# Opening inline div in new window with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, coupon

I am using a previous question in SO to help me with this "open-in-new-window" javascript function:

[Copy div And his style to new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894865/copy-div-and-his-style-to-new-window)

So my goal is to open an inline div in a new window and then to be able to print the new window (the div I want to open in the new window is a coupon).

I've accomplished styling the div (to look like a coupon) and set the javascript so that the div does indeed open in a new window, but

1) ...I can't get the style sheet to link to the new window,

2) ...and, I can't get the new window to print (instead nothing happens when I click to print the new window - but when I close the new window, the print dialogue box appears.

here is the code I'm using so far, any help is greatly appreciated:

```
$('#printCoupon').bind('click', function () {
    var printContents = new $("#coupon").clone();           
    var myWindow = window.open("", "popup", "width=600,height=380,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes," +
"toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=0,top=0");
    var doc = myWindow.document;
    doc.open();
$(printContents).find("#printCoupon").remove();
    doc.write("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">");
    doc.write("<html>");
    doc.write("<head>");
    doc.write("<link href='http://[link-to-css]/css/coupon.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />"); // your css file comes here.
    doc.write("</head>");
    doc.write("<body>");
    doc.write($(printContents).html());
    doc.write("</body>");
    doc.write("</html>");
});
```

and my html:

```
<div id="couponWrap">
    <div id="coupon">
        <h3>Coupon Title</h3>
        <p>Present this coupon and receive $10 off labor on your first service visit and 2% loyalty points on you next visit.</p>
    </div>
        <a href="javascript:;" id="printCoupon">Click to print this coupon.</a>
</div>
```

Thank you,
Cindy

Answer (score 0):

As far as writing, try the following (removed `doc.open()` and removed `popup` argument):

```
$('#printCoupon').bind('click', function () {
    var printContents = new $("#coupon").clone();           
    var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=600,height=380,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes," +
"toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=0,top=0");
    var doc = myWindow.document;
$(printContents).find("#printCoupon").remove();
    doc.write("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">");
    doc.write("<html>");
    doc.write("<head>");
    doc.write("<link href='http://[link-to-css]/css/coupon.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />"); // your css file comes here.
    doc.write("</head>");
    doc.write("<body>");
    doc.write($(printContents).html());
    doc.write("</body>");
    doc.write("</html>");
});
```

Comment: Using Chrome developer tool I see that the div tags using the ID are being striped from the new window - so any styling I have, which uses the ID of the div, can't be applied. I could use doc.write to add the div with the ID back into the HTML, but is there a better way? @gtr1971

Answer (score 0):

Did you check any issues based on whether your styles are element specific or not `@media print`? Go back to the reference you gave on where you based your example. Someone else commented this - maybe this is your issue:

> It depends on the way the div is styled. If the styles are applied
>   based on the ID or class then you should be fine to just include the
>   same stylesheet in the new window. However if any of the styles are
>   based on the element's ancestors then it becomes tricky as you would
>   have to copy the ancestral elements in order for the exact styles to
>   be applied.
>
> It sounds like you ought to be using print-specific styles. You can
>   apply a stylesheet to print only by including the media="screen"
>   attribute on the stylesheet link. This stylesheet is then responsible
>   for hiding any elements in the page that you don't want to print and
>   positioning the ones that you do. This way you are not subject to
>   popup blockers and give the user one less step to print the document.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions on setting up a print style sheet - if more coupons are added, I believe a good route to go. In this case, though all styles are based on the ID or class and are not based on another cascading style. Through Chrome I see that the ID is being stripped from the HTML code - so even with the stylesheet included in the new window, all HTML is simply defaulting to browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution thus far - the javascript stripped the divs from the HTML when opening in a new window, so I simply rewrote the div's back into the new window:

(does anyone know how to write the javascript to have multiple inline DIVs open in a new window when the inline DIVs are on the same webpage? I would need to dynamically generate the IDs, I believe in the code below and in the HTML.)

```
    $('#printCoupon').bind('click', function () {
var printContents = new $("#coupon").clone();           
var myWindow = window.open("width=600,height=380");
var doc = myWindow.document;
    $(printContents).find("#printCoupon").remove();
doc.write("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">");
doc.write("<html>");
doc.write("<head>");
doc.write("<link href='http://linktocssfile.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />"); // your css file comes here.
doc.write("</head>");
doc.write("<body>");
doc.write("<div id='coupon'>");
doc.write($(printContents).html());
doc.write("</div>");
doc.write("</body>");
doc.write("</html>");
});
```